# list permissions list of apps in Django front end

Tags: django, django-permissions

I want to list the permissions created by django for a model for specific app like it is done in django backend while creating users:

```
app_name | model_name | can add model_name
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve it from the Permissions model, like:

```
>>> Permission.objects.filter(content_type=ContentType.objects.get(app_label='auth',
model='user')) 

[<Permission: auth | user | Can add user>, <Permission:
auth | user | Can change user>, <Permission: auth | user | Can delete
user>]
```